# how to rename using variables batch

Tags: batch-file

So I have this block of code in my batch file that works

```
set /p projectnumber= enter project number: 
set /p projectname= enter project name: 
ren "C:\projects\temp.dwg" "19-%projectnumber% - %projectname%.dwg
```

So i tried this and it works

```
set /p projectnumber= enter project number: 
set /p projectname= enter project name: 
set _dwg="C:\projects\temp.dwg"
ren %_dwg% "19-%projectnumber% - %projectname%.dwg"
```

but what I would really like to have work is something like this

```
set /p projectnumber= enter project number: 
set /p projectname= enter project name: 
set _dwg="C:\projects\temp.dwg"
set _dwgrename="19-%projectnumber% - %projectname%.dwg"
ren %_dwg% %_dwgrename%
```

but it doesn't seem to work this is the first real batch file that I have written so I'm not sure why the second code works and the third ones doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues that need fixed.

1. Proper *Quoting*
2. Proper Usage Of `Set`
3. Proper Usage Of `Ren`

First up, we have quoting. I see you are trying to have `set _dwg` capture the entire path of `"C:\projects\temp.dwg"` however a proper way to do this is `set /switch "String=(Your data)"`. Because we are quoting the entire string, that means you will not have conflicts with spaces in file path.

Secondly, quickly wanted to address the space in your `set /p` statements - `projectnumber= enter` should not have a space after the `=`.

Lastly, I highly recommend you quote file path and destination on commands. For the `Ren` commands sake you will diffidently want to quote the file path as you are giving a path not a file name.

If you already dont know, you can use `echo off` to remove the console echo.

**Corrected Script:**

```
@ECHO OFF

set "_dwg=C:\projects\temp.dwg"

set /p "projectnumber=enter project number: "
set /p "projectname=enter project name: "
set "_dwgrename=19-%projectnumber% - %projectname%.dwg"

ren "%_dwg%" "%_dwgrename%"

pause
```

---

**PS:** Not sure if you're trying to subtract 19 from the `%projectnumber%` but if you are you may want to look into `set /a` or type `set /?` into an cmd window.